# How to load multiple models using ASSIMP's ReadFile function

Tags: c++, opengl

I was able to have a single model loaded by using 'Readfile' function in Assimp. It was then assigned to an aiScene pointer. Now i want to load multiple models of same format. How to achieve this? The documentation does not provide enough information on how to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main goal of the Assimp library is to load and postprocess your assets (e.g. model/scene), and it isn't for general scene-graph management. Usually you load your models into separate iaScene structures and translate them for your scene-graph one-by-one.

Comment: I will try creating several iascene pointers to hold loaded models. but im not sure if it is efficient when it comesto augmented realiy applications like mine. What are other easier to use model loaders out therr that fits my purpose? I want to load DAE (collada) files in an augmented reality project. thanks for your reply.

Comment: You shouldn't use the aiScene structure directly to render the scene, it's meant only for loading and post-processing. If you need a full scene-graph solution maybe you can check OpenScenegraph out.

Answer (score 2):

You can call `ReadFile` multiple times on a single `Assimp::Importer` object, but keep in mind that each invocation will free the previous `aiScene`. Therefore, the best thing you can do is to translate each scene directly into your own scenegraph as described by tbalazs.

If you *really* want to stick to `aiScene`, create a fresh importer object for each scene and keep it alive (i.e. store a list of *(scene, importer)* tuples somewhere) as long as needed.